How to Get-WinEvent Results to a Readable File Output
Attached Image
I am very new to Powershell so forgive me if this is a novice question, but I was having trouble searching the forum to find the specific answer I'm looking for.
After enable Auditing in gpedit.msc I came up with this script to grab and display the full details of what processes were created, UAC prompts failed, etc.:
get-winevent @{logname='security';id=4688,4648,4624} -maxevents 3 | fl

The issue I'm having is taking the results of the scripts and getting them to be in a readable outputted file format that I can present to someone on a daily or even weekly basis. This attached image is the gobbledygook I get when appending ConvertTo-Html at the end of it.
Does anyone have any tips? I would also appreciate any suggestions to make the script more robust and efficient regardless of the output issue.
Respectfully,
Ayo

Try removing fl (Format-List) at the end which formats the output for the screen and replace with Get-WinEvent @{logname = 'security'; id = 4688, 4648, 4624 } -MaxEvents 3 | ConvertTo-Html | Out-File mylog.html

Try piping to either Format-List or Format-Table

You're using Format-List (whose built-in alias is fl). However, Format-* cmdlets emit output objects whose sole purpose is to provide formatting instructions to PowerShell's for-display output-formatting system. In short: only ever use Format-* cmdlets to format data for display, never for subsequent programmatic processing. Piping its output to ConvertTo-Html is pointless. Directly piping Get-WinEvent's output to ConvertTo-Html, as recommended by @Daniel, should solve your problem. See the linked duplicate for background information.

@jdweng: not only is Format-List (in its alias form, fl) part of Ayo's own solution attempt, its use is the very cause of the problem.
